# Finding text outside of square brackets following start of specific string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to find the text outside of the square brackets following the specific string of [Name]. I will then create a new column in the DataFrame for the "Name" of the individuals. The order of the Information field can change, so for example, I am unable to call on the text between [Name] & [Age].

Example DataFrame:

```
Info = {'Information': ["[Name] Tom [Age] 22 [Height] 6'2","[Age] 21 [Name] Ben [Height] 6'0","[Age] 20 [Name] Mike [Height] 6'3"]}

df = DataFrame(Info,columns= ['Information'])
```

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
Name = []
for i in range(0,len(df)):
   start = 'Name]'
   end = '\['
   s = df["Information"].iloc[i]
   Name.append(s[s.find(start)+len(start):s.rfind(end)])
df["Name"] = Name
```

The output I receive in the newly created name column is:

```
[" Tom [Age] 22 [Height] 6'", " Ben [Height] 6'", "  Mike [Height] 6'"]
```

However I would like the output to be:

```
["Tom", "Ben", "Mike"]
```

I have also tried a similar loop using Regex and am unable to get the desired result.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is your goal to eventually extract Name, Age and Height?

Comment: As of right now it is just to extract Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also extract the data using split and a list comprehension:

```
[s.split("[Name]",1)[-1].split("[")[0].strip() for s in Info["Information"]]

# ['Tom', 'Ben', 'Mike']
```

**EDIT**

I made a few test with alternative methods but they all take about the same time (with 3 million items in the list):

Using split() : 1.47 sec

```
[s.split("[Name]",1)[-1].split("[",1)[0].strip() for s in Info["Information"]]
```

Using a compiled regular expression: 1.49 sec

```
import re
findName = re.compile(r".*\[Name\] (.+?) \[.*")
[findName.match(s).group(1) for s in Info["Information"]]
```

Using the index() function: 1.41 sec

```
[s[i+7:s.index(" [",i)] for s in Info["Information"] for i in [s.index("[Name] ")] ]
```

Avoiding strip() in the split() approach: 1.27 sec

```
[s.split("[Name] ",1)[-1].split(" [",1)[0] for s in Info["Information"]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, do you know if there is a faster alternative? With millions of rows it is taking a while to run.

Comment: I realized that there was an error in my code which was causing the program to take a very long time to run. Thank you for the edit and helping optimize run time!

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Name']=df['Information'].str.extract(r'\[Name\] (\w*)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Name'] = df.Information.str.extract(r'(?<=\[Name\])\s((?:\s*\w+)+)')
```

---

```
print(df)
              Information              Name
0   [Name] Tom [Age] 22 [Height] 6'2   Tom
1   [Age] 21 [Name] Ben [Height] 6'0   Ben
2  [Age] 20 [Name] Mike [Height] 6'3  Mike
```

Comment: Great, thank you. How would I extract the names of the individuals if I did not know the length? For example, if the first name was Tom Smith, second name was Ben Robert Johnson and the third name was Mike James William Thompson? Essentially I would like all of the text until the next "["

Comment: check now @BradKlassen

Comment: Great. I believe that will just pick up on the next delimiter though. It will end the text at either a "-" or "(". Is there a way to end it at "[" specifically?

Comment: Is the answer not working @BradKlassen why did you unaccept?

Comment: Good point. Ideally I would like it to end at "[" and if there is no other "[" to follow after the "[Name]" then I would likely use the above command you have provided 
r'(?<=\[Name\])\s((?:\s*\w+)+)'

Comment: Okay, well don't forget to accept if you find this helpful, thanks @BradKlassen